# What are the APIs heroku uses to manage postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

How the Heroku CLI tool manages DBs. What are the APIs they use? The tasks I am trying to do from the app are create/delete a postgres DB, create a dump, and import a dump using python code and not from the console or cli.

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly defined API for the Heroku Data products, unfortunately. That said, in my experience, the paths are fairly stable and can mostly be reasoned out. [This CLI plugin](https://github.com/uhoh-itsmaciek/heroku-data-api-plugin) might give you a head start on trying to work out the routes you'd need to hit in order to achieve your goals.